# UITableView Cells Empty

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

Im having a real issue with my UITableView, let me walk you through it.

I have a UITableViewController in my storyboard which has four different prototype cells each with their own identifiers.

Then I have this in my class for the controller:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"name";

    if (indexPath.section == 0) CellIdentifier = @"name";
    else if (indexPath.section == 1) CellIdentifier = @"name";
    else if (indexPath.section == 2 && indexPath.row == 0) CellIdentifier = @"segment";
    else if (indexPath.section == 2 && (indexPath.row == 1 || indexPath.row == 2 || indexPath.row == 3)) CellIdentifier = @"switch";
    else if (indexPath.section == 3) CellIdentifier = @"segment";
    else if (indexPath.section == 4) CellIdentifier = @"segment2";
    else if (indexPath.section == 5) CellIdentifier = @"name";
    else if (indexPath.section == 6) CellIdentifier = @"name";
    else if (indexPath.section == 7) CellIdentifier = @"name";

    GuestDetailCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[GuestDetailCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    //Configure my cells here, like so:
    if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        cell.title.text = @"title";
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 1)
    {

    }
    //etc

    return cell;
}
```

I think this is where my problem lies, as I have had success with some different code (which I will add if you might need to see it, let me know.

The right number of cells show in the table and right number of sections and if you select a cell it takes you to the right sub-viewcontroller, but the actual cells themselves are just blank. Why might they all be returning nil?

Now when the view is shown, all the cells are blank. `cell = [[GuestDetailCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];` This seems to be called over and over, opposed to my cells as configured showing.

I get to this view by calling this code:

```
- (void)addNewGuest
{
    newGuestViewController *addGuestViewController = [[newGuestViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    addGuestViewController.delegate = self;

    //Create a new managed object context for the new guest -- set its persistent store coordinator to the same as that from the fetched results controller's context.
    NSManagedObjectContext *addingContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    self.addingManagedObjectContext = addingContext;

    [addingManagedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:[[fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext] persistentStoreCoordinator]];

    addGuestViewController.guest = (GuestInfo *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"GuestInfo" inManagedObjectContext:addingContext];

    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:addGuestViewController];

    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
}
```

Any ideas, or need more info?

Thanks.

Comment: first of all: Please be sure to write your classes and instances in the right camelCasing. Classes ALWAYS begin uppercase and instances lowercase!

Comment: The cells aren't nil, that would be a run-time exception and a crash. I'd start with inspecting the cell in the debugger, particularly it's properties - how and when are you creating all of the labels etc in the cell?

Comment: I though something interesting though was that if I put `cell.textLabel.text = @"test";` in the if statement checking if the cell is equal to nil, all of my cells show the 'test' text. So `cell = [[GuestDetailCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];` is being called when it shouldn't be right? Surely that overrides my customisation of the cells?

Comment: Having said that, I think your right it might be to do with how I am using the UILabels. I simply have dropped my label into the cell in my storyboard and hooked up the outlets to my custom cell class (which simply has a declaration of the labels in, nothing else). Then in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, I just change the text depending on the indexPath as required. So how exactly should I be handling them?

Comment: You must have the same reuse identifiers set in the storyboard as you are using in code. If you do that, dequeue will _always_ return a cell, and you'll never need to instantiate one.

Answer (score 0):

This drove me crazy. Stumped me right in front of the client. jrturton's comment had the answer I needed. Blew past this question initially since it didn't have any answers. Posting jrturton's comment as an answer so it is less likely to be overlooked. Here is his comment(answer):

> You must have the same reuse identifiers set in the storyboard as you
>   are using in code. If you do that, dequeue will always return a cell,
>   and you'll never need to instantiate one.